# Maven build deployment

Tags: deployment, maven-2, build

I have to manually deploy my servlet war packages on an Apache tomcat instance running on an AWS (Amazon Web Services) machine (remote server).

Also i have Maven setup for dependency management and build packaging in local development environment.

What I want is to setup my maven install/deploy task such that my packaged war files are deployed and configured(i.e executing specific shell scripts) on the remote server automatically.

Is it possible ?

If yes!!

How can it be done? (Please suggest relevant references.)

Thanks in advance

Ashish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you can use the [cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) to deploy to a server. See the [Getting Started](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin#Maven2plugin-gettingstarted) page for some examples.

If your scripts aren't catered for by the plugin, perhaps you could post some more details to see what options there are to address them.

Comment: Yes Cargo can be used in my case, but i also need to deploy custom xml config files, launch one or more instances of applications (e.g. running open office in server mode etc), transfer and execute custom shell scripts on my currently running EC2 instance, can it be integrated with maven and how?

Comment: I used cargo but i am unable to get it deploy past a proxy server.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about Amazon's Elastic Computing Cloud (EC2), maybe you could check out [cloudtools](http://code.google.com/p/cloudtools/) and its [maven plugin](http://code.google.com/p/cloudtools/wiki/UsingTheCloudToolsMavenPlugin) (see the [announcement](http://chris-richardson.blog-city.com/ec2deploy_and_the_cloud_tools_maven_plugin_are_now_available.htm) on Chris Richardson's blog). Never tested myself though.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for cargo plugin, I was not aware of that but could use it myself.

In case it helps you or someone else, you can run any script upon launch of an instance.  [This blog](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com/2009/07/simple-example-of-customizing-aws-ec2.html) describes how.